# Try to using lightning component instead of single related list in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Since Article related list without detach file action per record, we want to build lightning component instead.
When we try to display records first ,found below errors

> Failed to save Case_CaseArticleCom.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://aura:interation found : [markup://c:Case_CaseArticleCom]: Source"

Please help to solve this,thanks.

Component

```
<aura:component Controller="Case_CaseArticleComCtrl" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="caseArticleNumber" type="Integer" />
    <aura:attribute name="caseArticles" type="CaseArticle" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <article class="slds-card">
          <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <header class="slds-media slds-media_center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
              <div class="slds-media__figure">
                  <c:svgIcon svgPath="/resource/SLDS/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#article" category="standard" size="" name="article" />
              </div>
              <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h2 class="slds-card__header-title">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-card__header-link slds-truncate" title="Articles">
                    <span class="slds-text-heading_small">Articles</span>
                    </a>
                </h2>
              </div>
            </header>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-card__body">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_bordered slds-no-row-hover slds-table_cell-buffer">
              <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Article">Article</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Modified Date">Modified Date</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Created By">Created By</div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Detach File">Detach File</div>
                  </th>  
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <aura:interation items="{!v.caseArticles}" var ="caseArticle" >  
                <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                  <th scope="row">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.Title}">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0);">{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.Title}</a>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.LastModifiedDate}">{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.LastModifiedDate}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.CreatedBy.Name}">{!caseArticle.KnowledgeArticleVersion.CreatedBy.Name}
                    </div>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    Detach files
                  </td>
                </tr>
                  </aura:interation> 
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <footer class="slds-card__footer">
            <a class="slds-card__footer-action" href="javascript:void(0);">View All
              <span class="slds-assistive-text">Articles</span>
            </a>
          </footer>
        </article>   
</aura:component>`

Component Controller

    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getCaseArticle(component);
    }
})
```

Helper

```
({
    getCaseArticle : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getCaseArticle");
        action.setParams({
            caseId :component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this,function(actionResult){
            component.set('v.caseArticles',actionResult.getReturnValue());               
        })
        $A.enqueueAction(action)
    }
})`
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class Case_CaseArticleComCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<CaseArticle> getCaseArticle(String caseId){
        Return [SELECT Id,CaseId,KnowledgeArticleVersion.LastModifiedDate, KnowledgeArticleVersion.Title, KnowledgeArticleVersion.CreatedBy.Name,KnowledgeArticleVersion.UrlName,KnowledgeArticleVersionId 
        FROM CaseArticle
        WHERE CaseId = :caseId
        ];

    }


}
```

Comment: After little adjustment and add lightning component to case lightning record page. Found that ,when case loaded or refreshed, the related list will be display correctly, once attached article or detached file from knowledge component in same page, the component is not correct since the component is not refreshed. Unknow how to deal with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a typo in the code .

There is nothing called **aura:interation** .Replace it with the **[aura:iteration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_iteration.htm)** .